# Как в JavaScript ES5 и ES6 сделать приватные свойства класса?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, наследование, ecmascript-6

Причем не протектед, которые принято именовать начиная с подчеркивания `this._play()`, а именно приватные, чтобы они не были доступны не только извне, а также и классам наследникам, чтобы случайно не возникали конфликты имен.

Причем желательно без использования Symbol, так как он поддерживается не везде.

Понятно что в ES6 он есть, а вот в ES5 как с ним быть?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

А ВОТ ТАК (при чем так можно делать уже 200 лет отроду):

ES6:

```
var say = Symbol()

class Cat {

   constructor(){
      this[say]() // call private
   }

   [say](){
      alert('im private')
   }

}
```

ES5:

```
var say = Math.random() // like Symbol()

function Cat(){
  this[say]() // call private methods
}

Cat.prototype[say] = function(){ alert('im a private') }
```

Пример использования ES6:

```
var handlers = Symbol()

class EventEmitter {

  constructor(){
    this[handlers] = [] 
  }


  on(handler){
    this[handlers].push(handler) 
  }

  emit(){
    for(let handler of this[handlers]) handler()
  }

}


class Cat extends EventEmitter {

}


var q = new Cat()
q.on // function
q.emit // function
q.handlers // undefined cuz PRIVATE ;)
```

И не обязательно больше учить названия свойств из реализации класса, таких как внутреннее свойство handlers, боясь их случайно перекрыть в классах наследниках. Использую приватные уже 6 лет. И ни каких проблем с утечками. Не понимаю людей которые говорят что в яваскрипте приватных нет.

Наслаждайтесь ;)

Comment: И где  в вашем ответе у ES6 `При чем желательно без использования Symbol так как он поддерживается не везде` ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42635/discussion-between-maxmaxmaximus-and--).

Answer (score 0):

как вариант

```
function MyClass() {
  var self = this;
  self.one = 1; // private;
  self.two = 2;
  return {
    add: function(val) {
      return self.one + val;
    },
    two: self.two
  }
}

var mc = new MyClass();
console.log(mc.add(mc.two));
```

Comment: если убрать `self` и вместо этого сделать просто `var one=1` и вызывать без `new` - намного красивее будет выглядеть

Comment: феноминально, почему я раньше так не писал? XD